# device back button override in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to override **Device back button**, I tried `willowpopscope()` but that adds back button on top application or we can call it Appbar.

But I don't wanna use top back button I want to override the device (Mobile system) back button. For example I want to go to a particular page/activity when device back button is pressed. How I can achieve that?

Note: `willowpopscope` is only adding back button in app bar not doing anything related to device back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **back_button_interceptor** which is just published few days ago.
it helps to override **device back button**

**Syntax** to use back_button_interceptor is

```
@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   BackButtonInterceptor.add(myInterceptor);
}

@override
void dispose() {
   BackButtonInterceptor.remove(myInterceptor);
   super.dispose();
}

bool myInterceptor(bool stopDefaultButtonEvent) {
   print("BACK BUTTON!"); // Do some stuff.
   return true;
}
```

this is how you can override the actual device back button

now look at the example

```
import 'package:back_button_interceptor/back_button_interceptor.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ListTab createState() => ListTab();
}
class ListTab extends State<MyWidget> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BackButtonInterceptor.add(myInterceptor);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    BackButtonInterceptor.remove(myInterceptor);
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool myInterceptor(bool stopDefaultButtonEvent) {
    Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>App())
    );
    return true;
  }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          body: new Center(
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
            Container(
            child: new Text(
              "USER_PAGE",
            ),
          ),

      ])));
      }


}
```

:D done!!